# converting coordinates from sfc object to dataframe and plotting them

Tags: r

```
library(rworldmap)
library(sf)
library(spData)
library(sfheaders)
```

I made a polygon of Germany

```
ger <- world[world$name_long == "Germany", 0]
plot(ger)
```

[image]

And inside that polygon I sample 1000 random points which I plot

```
p_ger <- st_sample(ger, size = 1000, type = "random", crs = st_crs(4326))
plot(p_ger)
```

[image]

As we can see, plotted points look like Geramany.
However, when I transform sfc object produced by st_sample function into a dataframe, plotted map of Germany looks completely different.

```
df_ger <- sfc_to_df(p_ger)
df_ger2<-df_ger[,3:4]

plot(df_ger2)
```

[image]

I would like to know why and how can I prevent it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `sf` object has a coordinate system, or CRS. In this case its "WGS84":

```
> ger
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 5.988658 ymin: 47.30249 xmax: 15.017 ymax: 54.9831
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
```

When plotted, `sf` will adjust lat-long data to look "right" because the distance of one degree of longitude on the earth gets smaller as you get nearer the poles. If you convert to a data frame that metadata is lost and R plots it with 1 degree latitude the same size as one degree of longitude. Things away from the equator will look squashed.

This can be "fixed" in a base R plot by specifying the aspect ratio with the `asp` parameter:

```
plot(df_ger2, asp=1.7)
```

[image]

The exact value depends on the latitude and can be derived with some trigonometry which I can't remember off-hand but you can probably look up. It'll be 1 at the equator and infinite at the poles.  But 1.7 looks about right here.

The other option is to transform your data out of lat-long to a cartesian projected coordinate system, which will approximate the spherical lat-long data to a flat plane. For small areas this works well, but for large areas introduces distortions in distance and angles - for example the well-known Mercator map that makes Greenland look as big as Africa. For Germany there's probably some official map projection standard, or there's the correct UTM zone system, or you can use a standard European coordinate system such as epsg:3035.

```
> ger = st_transform(ger, "epsg:3035")
> plot(ger)
> axis(1)
> axis(2)
```

New `ger` is in metres:

[image]

as you can see from the axes, and points sampled in it will have the same coordinate system and so a dataframe of those points will still be in a metre-grid and look okay without adjusting the aspect ratio on plotting.